# XEn server and san

Tags: xenserver

I explain the situation I would create a volume (Mon) 4 server share on this part is successful with (multiple host access) but the second part is the problem i try to have my  real-time synchronization of files. I add a file to the volume of a particular server and would like to access it from another server but it impossible to see the file. If I put my volume offline and put it back online I see.

i search on the web and i not my technique not work.

I need help to build a scenario with my san.

Can i do this whith technique i dont no

excuse me for my english my first language it the french

Comment: Two questions.  Are you running a clustered file system such at GFS or OCFS to allow the proper distributed locking required to have multiple systems mount one filesystem?  And are you mounting this LUN from the virtual machines or in Dom0 and passing this to each of the virtual machines?

Answer (score 2):

Standard filesystems (NTFS, FAT, EXT3-2, ...) cannot be accessed by multiple nodes at a time. They are meant to be accessed by a single node and are therefore simpler.

If you need a filesystem to be available by several nodes at block level, you should consider GFS or OCFS. If you need a filesystem to be available by serveral nodes at file level, you should consider NFS or CIFS.

Answer (score 0):

In our company we use XenServer together with [StarWind iSCSI SAN](http://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind). Thus, we did not need to buy a special hardware but turned a generic server into SAN.